# The reversible Carnot cycle is the most efficient between $T_2$ and $T_1$. Is it a form the second law itself?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, reversibility, carnot-cycle

The second law of thermodynamics
proposed by Clausius, Kelvin, Carnot ..etc in its original form  as T dS> dQ for irreversible process  and  Tds =dQ only for reversible thermodynamics process.

This particular formulation may be stated in many "equivalent" forms most common  is : The Carnot cycle is the most thermally efficient between T2 and T1.
 However, there is still controversy debate: this statement can not be exactly equal to the second law it is just a corollary?

Answer (score 0):

> The Carnot cycle is the most thermally efficient between T2 and T1. However, there is still controversy debate: this statement can not be exactly equal to the second law it is just a corollary?

It's my understanding it is a corollary to the Kelvin Plank statement of the second law.

**Kelvin-Planck Statement of Second Law**
*No heat engine can operate in a cycle while transferring heat with a single heat reservoir.*

*COROLLARY* to Kelvin-Planck: No heat engine can have a higher efficiency than a Carnot Cycle operating between the same reservoirs

**Clausius' Statement of Second Law**
*No refrigeration or heat pump cycle can operate without a net work input*

COROLLARY: No refrigerator or heat pump can have a higher COP than a Carnot Cycle refrigeratore or heat pump.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Bob D-, Thanks for this precious answer. .